# unable to count records for an interval in days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to detect how many records are covered by a certain period in a RedShift table. So I queried records for various periods of time. However I've noticed a strange behavior.

When I'm trying to count a number of records for say 100 days it returns 0 no matter how many days I'm executing the query for.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM main.transaction_data
WHERE tr_date > current_date - interval '100' day;
```

But when I query the count for several months it returns a valid count.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM main.transaction_data
WHERE tr_date > current_date - interval '3 months';
```

Is the query for a period of 100 days incorrect?

Comment: Does that second query really execute? (Invalid interval literal.)

Comment: And you are sure there are rows older than 100 days? Have you tried `current_date  - interval '4' months`?

Comment: @jarlh I have executed the second query again (for the 4 months interval) and it returned the count successfully

Comment: And if you try `interval '100 day'` rather than `interval '100' day`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff wow that did the trick. thanks!

Comment: Weird, that syntax is the opposite to the ANSI SQL specification...

Comment: @samba . . . I'm voting to close as a simple typographical error.